# which mecanism to choose the good jdk from pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, build, version

i'd like to understand how maven choose the good jdk to build a java project,
when i have two different jdks installed ?
For example :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/bin/
/usr/lib/jvm/oracle-jdk-17/bin/
```

and this pom.xml

```
 <properties>
      <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
      <springboot.version>2.6.4</springboot.version>
 </properties>
```

How maven choose the jdk to build the project ?
what system variable or config do i have to check ?

Comment: Maven uses `JAVA_HOME` to select the JDK (check via: `mvn --version`)...

Comment: @khmarbaise ok, so why referencing the version of the jdk into the pom.xml ? what is the logic ?

Comment: That is not a reference to the jdk. Its to define which version the class files will be compiled to and which in consequence defines the minimum version of java runtime which is need to run this project...

Comment: @khmarbaise absolutly clear !

Comment: @khmarbaise a different and last question : the result of a build of a (java8 project with jdk8) and a (java8 project with jdk17) should result in strictly same *.class files, isn't it ? If yes, how can we be sure of this ? By testing with the same jdk as run jdk, or it is not necessary ?

Comment: Several large project (small project me included) building with JDK11, 17 and producing files for JDK 8 and this is working 100%.. for example JUnit Jupiter (doing that for a very long time)..I would say not necessary...(wasted time)... So you can allways build with the highest LTS or even others and produce for an appopriate target for example 8...